# Can i run multiple instances of Android Monitor simultaneously?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, memory

I have 2 android devices running 2 different versions of my app.

I want to monitor their memory usage etc. using Android Monitor.

The problem is that Android Monitor allows me to monitor only either one of them at a time.

[image: Android Monitor Devices]

I know i can run 2 instances of Android Studio and this way i get 2 instances of Android Monitor but i'm looking for a better solution.

So how can i monitor 2 devices simultaneously using the Android Monitor and only one instance of Android Studio?

**Or maybe someone could point me to a third party software that can monitor android devices?**

Cheers, Robert

Answer (score 0):

> So how can i monitor 2 devices simultaneously using the Android Monitor and only one instance of Android Studio?

You can't. You can swap between the devices to see both, but there is no way to see both device's logs at the same time with only one AS instance

Comment: I see, that's a shame. How about my second question? :D